# Objective C - How to determine if a folder is a package?

Tags: objective-c, package

App Packages are basically folders and you can read their contents just like any folders. I understood this.

My question is:

If I have a folder called folderA which has files and a package called PackageA which has files, how can I programmatically tell what is a normal folder and what is a package ?

In my application I need to exclude any packages but process any normal folders.

Any advise would be appreciated.

I have tried to check via NSBundle but both normal folder as well as package folder is an NSBundle. I was hoping one is not. I am sure there is a property that will tell me that?

I solved it as:

```
NSNumber *isPackage;
NSError *error = nil;

[filePath getResourceValue:&isPackage forKey:NSURLIsPackageKey error:&error];

if( [isPackage integerValue] == 1)
{
    // treat as package
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, the "modern" way is to use `NSURL`'s `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` method (or one of its siblings). The key for determining whether the `NSURL` instance references a package is `NSURLIsPackageKey`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to do exactly what I need. I added my code to the initial post. Let me know if not used correctly.

Comment: @Mozzak - `if ([isPackage boolValue])` is more direct than asking for the `integerValue` and comparing to `1`. You haven't checked for errors (the method returns `NO` and sets `error`). But both are minor *in this particular case* (generally you should check for errors).

Comment: makes sense. I should check for errors for sure. Also boolValue is a good tip. Coming from Windows Programming. Still getting used to the objective c way of things. thanks again for all your help.